# MONGODB redact array

Tags: mongodb

i just want to understand $redact in mongodb 
suppose i have a collection like .

```
db.tab12.find()

{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "jan", "passport" : [ "usa" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "jaan", "passport" : [ "usa", "canada" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "name" : "jon", "passport" : [ "germany" ] }
```

and i run the following command

```
db.tab12.aggregate({$match:{"name":{$regex:"a"}}},{$redact:{$cond:{if:{$in:["$country",["canada"]]},then:"$$DESCEND",else:"$$PRUNE" }} } )
```

I get no result, mongodb lacks examples on net i think.

Comment: There are examples in the docs for the [`$redact` stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#examples) and the [Field Level Redaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/) tutorial. The intended use of this aggregation stage is to remove embedded documents based on a set of access tags determining user visibility. The document samples in your question aren't the right structure or use case for `$redact` (`$filter` would be more appropriate to remove array values).

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you have collections **PC** and **events**. The PC is generating a different type of events and you want just to take the events which are from type:1

```
PC {
"_id": ObjectId,
"version": "SomeVersion",
"location": "Sofia",
"price": 220,
 events: [1,2,3,4,5]
}

events{
"_id":1,
"type": 1,
"ts": "1999-01-01"
}

events{
"_id":2,
"securiy:" true,
"type": 2,
"ts": "2015-01-01"
}

PCs.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            "location": "Sofia"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$events'
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            events: '$pcs.events'
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$events'
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'events',
            localField: 'event',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'events'
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [{
              'events.ts': {
                $gt: new Date("1970-01-01")
              }
            },
            {
              'events.ts': {
                $lt: new Date("2000-02-02")
              }
            }
            ] 
          }
        },
        {
          $redact: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ '$events.type', 1 ] },
              then: '$$KEEP',
              else: '$$PRUNE'
            }
          }
        },
```

this will remove all the other type of events, which are not passing the condition. After this step you can make some kind of grouping and for example if the events have some data (for example price), you can sum it.

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      isSecurityEvent: '$events.security',
    },
    totalEvents: { $sum: 1 },
    }
  }
}
```

])

From the [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#examples) you have 3 types of operators:

> System Variable   Description
>
> $$DESCEND $redact **returns the fields at
> the current document level, excluding embedded documents. To include
> embedded documents and embedded documents within arrays, apply the
> $cond expression to the embedded documents to determine access for
> these embedded documents.**
>
> $$PRUNE   $redact **excludes all fields at this current
> document/embedded document level, without further inspection of any of
> the excluded fields. This applies even if the excluded field contains
> embedded documents that may have different access levels.**
>
> $$KEEP    $redact **returns or keeps all fields at this current
> document/embedded document level, without further inspection of the
> fields at this level. This applies even if the included field contains
> embedded documents that may have different access levels.**